# Using RelativeLayout to offset center align ProgressBar view?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've an ImageView that serves as the background of the image and at the same time a preloader horizontally and vertically aligning in the center of the screen. I managed to center the progressBar but wasn't able to offset it slightly above using margin.

Some people suggested to use **linearLayout** and control using `android:layout_weight`, however it doesn't work for me as I need to apply my image as background and hence the **relativeLayout**...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="#FE6869"
          android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />


</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to align the progressbar both horizontally center and vertically but I want the progress bar to be able to position slightly above/below relative to the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="#FE6869"
          android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to work out the positioning using the nested layouts you create.